# Do we really need the metallic chassis to be grounded if it is coated with a non-conductive paint?

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, shock

[image]

As per my understanding, a metallic chassis can result in a shock **only** if two failures happen simultaneously:

1. Live wire ('hot') insulation wears off and gets in contact with chassis.
2. Chassis outer painting is worn off and person touches the same point.

I am not sure whether my understanding of the second point is correct.

- When I measure the continuity on the metallic chassis of most of the lab equipment (electronic load, power supply unit, laptop), I see high resistance. I assume this is due to the non-conductive paint/outer coating.
- Say the paint is intact and the live wire is shorted to the chassis. This would raise the chassis potential to dangerously high values. **Would the paint insulation breakdown or overall setup just act like a capacitor (paint being the dielectric)?**

Comment: Even plastic is required to be double insulated. Paint chips, can be applied unevenly and inconsistently, and is not dieelectric rated. Now powder coating is much better than paint but I still wouldn't rely on it for safety insulation. For insulating for operation maybe, but not safety. I have seen things spark through non-conductive coatings too.

Comment: "... Would the paint insulation breakdown or overall setup just act like a capacitor (paint being the dielectric)?"  Nobody knows, because **paint does not typically have any recognized approvals or ratings**.  As such, it is your responsibility to do things according to the rules, or accept responsibility if things go very wrong.

Comment: Who know what will happen to some paint in case you get currents through the metal underneath, including potential galvanic hiccups between the metal and whatever is in the paint... It seems to me that 1) failing could likely lead to 2) failing too, particularly over time.

Comment: If that's a 2 pin lead it could be plugged in either way, so either wire could short to the chassis for step 1 to take place.

Comment: Also, screws...

Comment: The case is not going to be painted on the inside, so it still means a GFCI will trip if something internally connects mains to the case.

Comment: Paint tends to wear first exactly where a human is most likely to touch the device. The corners in particular.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Would the paint insulation breakdown or overall setup just act like a
> capacitor (paint being the dielectric)?

Not if you want to run this through regulatory, paint is probably not sufficient enough to qualify as an insulator as it can be scratched. If no ground is used then you need to be double insulated in order to be safe (class II product, class I has ground). Insulation can fail, it is unlikely that insulation will fail twice and not in the same spot, being doubly insulated is safe.

> A Class II or double insulated electrical appliance uses reinforced
> protective insulation in addition to basic insulation. Hence, it has
> been designed in such a way that it does not require a safety
> connection to electrical earth (ground).
>
> The basic requirement is that no single failure can result in
> dangerous voltage becoming exposed so that it might cause an electric
> shock and that this is achieved without relying on an earthed metal
> casing. This is usually achieved at least in part by having at least
> two layers of insulating material between live parts and the user, or
> by using reinforced insulation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes

Answer (score 10):

A paint coating is thin and fragile.

A plastic outer shell that meets double insulation standards needs to be thick and robust.

There are standards for how much physical abuse an outer shell should be able to take without failing. Whether they can be found easily, or this side of a paywall, is another matter. If you find a suitable publication, feel free to edit in a link to it, or a comment below.

Comment: Having used old hardware for rough and ready drop tests, in most cases it's *a lot* of physical abuse. The drop test to destruction of a glued mirror assembly that I did trashed a plastic printer (a dead inkjet), but it took repeated drops from 2m+ onto concrete. Our assembly inside survived so in the end we used a steel PC case - obviously class 1 - from over 3m (which damaged the concrete, snapped the mirror, but the glue held). The plastic front of the case still wouldn't have let a finger in.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you should ground your metallic chassis even though it is coated in non-conductive paint.**

[Read this article on appliance classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes). It breaksdown the different types of insulation/safety categories. When releasing a product to market, it will have to be certified by a certification body. They won't let that one slip!

The only instances where I have seen a product connected to 120V/220V which had an ungrounded case was double insulated and bared the Class II symbol.

For your 2 other questions:

- I agree with you, most likely the paint increases the resistance.
- To be fair, I don't know. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Most metal chassis use screws or pop rivets to fix them.

Either a screw hole will not be painted so the threads are not blocked, or the screw will cut through the paint when inserted. Similarly pop rivets will often break through any paint to bare metal.

So even if there was some paint which was an approved insulator, the fixings would present a hazard.

(when repairing old live chassis radio gear, you have to make sure that the feet for example are not exposing any touchable screws, often these need replacing with modern plastic ones instead)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the paint would act like a capacitor, and yes, it would possibly break down and arc to the person touching it (depending on the paint properties, of course). When AC live is at peak potential (120V × √2 = 170V), the circuit would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNoYfx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left is a potential divider between the AC live and ground, formed by the high resistance paint and the low resistance person. Almost the entire 170V potential difference lies across the paint, and it could easily break down and arc.

If that happened, you'd have the circuit on the right, where the person gets hurt or killed.

If no break-down occurs, you still have the capacitance you mentioned:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fByjfQ.png)</sup>

If you placed the entire palm of your hand against the paint, capacitance of C1 could be many nanofarads. The AC voltage across your body could be tens of volts, depending on your own resistance. You'd probably feel it, and it might even be painful.

Always ground metallic chassis.